# In angular, assign values to nested object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 2 application. I have object with nested object 'subQuestions'. I need to assign values to it but getting error as subQuestionId is not recognise. subQuestionId is property of subQuestions

### error

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'subQuestionId' of undefined
```

### data class

```
export class AnswerEntryDataModel{

consultationId:string;
responseId:string;
questionId:string;
answers:string[];
isPreDefineAnswer:boolean;
subQuestions:{
    subQuestionId:string;
    isPreDefineSubAnswer:boolean;
    subQuestionAnswers:string[];
 }
}
```

### Component

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

private answerData = new AnswerEntryDataModel();
private answersList:string [] = []; 
private subQuestionAnswersList:string [] = []; 

 private assembleAnswer( responseId:string, questionId:string, subQuestionId:string, subQuestionInputType:string, subQuestionAnswersList:string[] ):AnswerEntryDataModel
{

  this.answerData.answers = [];

  this.answerData.consultationId = this.session.getItem('consultationId');
  this.answerData.responseId = responseId;
  this.answerData.questionId = questionId;

  if(subQuestionId!=null || subQuestionId!="undefined")
  {

    answerData.subQuestions.subQuestionId = subQuestionId; //throw error from here

    if(subQuestionInputType =="textbox"){  
      this.answerData.subQuestions.isPreDefineSubAnswer = false;
    }
    else {
      this.answerData.subQuestions.isPreDefineSubAnswer = true;
    }

    if(subQuestionAnswersList.length>0)
    {
      for(var itemIndex in subQuestionAnswersList)
      {
        this.answerData.subQuestions.subQuestionAnswers.push(subQuestionAnswersList[itemIndex]);
      }
    }

  }

  console.log("***** complete answer data ", this.answerData);

  return this.answerData;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'subQuestionId' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

`subQuestions` is an object not yet instantiated.

You could get rid of this error like:

```
answerData.subQuestions = { subQuestionId: subQuestionId };
```